# unlink repository from central server in bazaar

Tags: bazaar

Every time I commit with bazaar, it contacts my remote repository (the one I got the code from). I want to commit locally, because the development machine I'm on is offline. Of course there's the --local option, but I would like just to remove the linkage between the remote server and the repository branch. How can I do it?

Related question: once I get back online with the repo, what is the procedure to submit the changes to the central repository ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bzr unbind
```

See http://doc.bazaar-vcs.org/latest/en/user-guide/using_checkouts.html

```
bzr bind [LOCATION]
```

converts the local branch into a checkout of the central repository.

Comment: `bzr unbind` worked for me, but I did get the following error message (despite an apparently successful local commit): `bzr: ERROR: Local branch is not bound`. This may be due to my nonstandard repo and branch inits.

Answer (score 1):

You have checkout (or bound branch) of the master branch from your server. Most likely you have used command:

```
bzr checkout URL
```

Your checkout can be unbind from the master branch with command:

```
bzr unbind
```

The command above will "convert" your checkout to plain branch.

Once you got back online you can bind again to your master branch with command:

```
bzr bind
```

To commit your local changes to master branch you need to run update command first:

```
bzr update
```

The command above will convert all your local commits into pending merge. You can see that all your revisions are waiting to commit by commands:

```
bzr status
```

or

```
bzr qlog
```

(qlog is graphical log from QBzr plugin).

There is possible conflicts, check them with `bzr conflicts` command. Resolve them before commit and run command `bzr resolve`.

Once you commit all your local revisions will appear as merged revisions in master branch on the server and your local branch will be fully synchronized with master branch.

**Warning**: if you don't want to commit your local revisions after you made `bzr update` then you should not run `bzr revert`, because it will hide all your local commits. Instead use `bzr unbind` again and `bzr pull . --overwrite -r YOUR_LOCAL_COMMITS_TIP`.